# I want to save data in DB using fill but I get an error

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder, laravel-5.8

I want to read and overwrite existing data

**ProjectController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $param = Project::find($id);
    $param = fill($request)->save();
    return redirect('/project');
}
```

I get this error and can't use fill

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\fill()
```

And I tried

```
$param = Project::fill($request)->save();
```

But i got this error

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() should not be called statically
```

And this too

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $param = Project::find($id);
    $param->fill($request)->save();
    return redirect('/project');
}
```

It was like this

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array, object given, called in
```

It worked fine after adding all ()

```
$param->fill($request->all())->save();
```

**Thanks for your cooperation**

Comment: Where is this function created?

Comment: @Adam Hull  I am writing in ProjectController

Comment: Would it not need to be ```Project::fill```

Comment: @AdamHull I tryed $param = Project::fill($request)->save();But the non-static method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Model :: fill () should not be called statically

Comment: Try using ```$project = new Project; $project->fill($request)->save();```

Comment: @user3783243 The longest message is back Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array, object given, called in

Comment: @AdamHull I did it but it didn't work

Comment: Sounds like you have conflicting data types, and that `fill` is a function of `find`.

Comment: @user3783243 Using all () worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all after fill worked

```
$param->fill($request->all())->save();
```